# What are the best deep learning algorithms to create a NN for blind source separation?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I want to program a NN for finding the source of a combination of images.

a*img1 + b*img2   as the input
we aim to find img1 and img2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn what questions this site is for (programming questions).